# Calculating the velocity of ejecta from an asteroid impact

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Somewhat naively, I'm trying to figure out how to create a very basic model of collisions between celestial bodies and the nature of the ejecta clouds produced by such impacts.

Say, for example, that an asteroid with a mass of 3.51e10 kg strikes the Moon at a velocity of 20 km/s: what will the intitial velocity of the ejecta be? Once you have an initial velocity, I know that taking the angle at which the ejecta is ejected coupled with the gravity of the Moon allows you to calculate how far the ejecta will travel, but I can't figure out how to get the initial velocity.

I can calculate the kinetic energy released by the impact, but how do you go from there to figuring out the velocity at which a mass of 2 kg would be hurled thereafter?

I realise that the scope of my question is very broad, and for that I apologise in advance. I also realise that there are a multitude of factors that need to be taken into account such as the material composition of the Moon's surface and so on, but if somebody could give me an idea as to how I could go about finding a very naive but physically plausible answer to my question, that would be massively appreciated!

Comment: I thought this book was pretty good: Impact cratering: A geologic process, 
Melosh, H. J.

Comment: Generally, check the papers of Melosh for some impact modelling.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm looking into his work now!